# How to test DAO layer in Java Web application using Mockito and PowerMock in Eclipse and Tomcat 8?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, tomcat, jdbc

I'm new to JavaEE and I'm having troubles with testing my app using Mockito and PowerMock.
I found how to test servlets, but my DAO layer is configured with Tomcat Connection Pool with MySQL and I can't find how to make it work. Almost all of my classes use a DB to get information and I can't test them because of this problem. Help me, please.

My connection pool configuration file

```
context.xml
<Context path="/Payments">
<Resource name="jdbc/payments_base"
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="10000"
        username="root" password="root" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        defaultAutoCommit="false"
        defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payments_base"
        connectionProperties="useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;"/>
</Context>
```

Some code from DAO class:

```
public class DBManager {

private static DBManager instance;

public static synchronized DBManager getInstance() {
if (instance == null) {
    instance = new DBManager();
}
return instance;
}
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
Connection con = null;
try {
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/payments_base");
    con = ds.getConnection();
} catch (NamingException e) {
    LOG.error("Cannot obtain a connection from the pool", e);
}
return con;
}
   private User extractUser(ResultSet rs) {
   User user = new User();
   LOG.trace("Exctracting user from DB");
   try {
     user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
     user.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
     user.setPassword(rs.getString("pass"));
     user.setFirstName(rs.getString("first_name"));
     user.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
     user.setRole(Role.getRole(rs.getInt("role_id")));
   } catch (SQLException e) {
     LOG.error("Cannot extract User from db", e);
   }
   return user;
}
}
```

Command that I want to test

```
public class LoginCommand extends Command {

@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Locale loc = new Locale(session.getAttribute("language").toString());
ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle
    .getBundle("ua.nure.bandura.Payments.i18n.text", loc);
DBManager manager = DBManager.getInstance();
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("pass");
String errorMessage = null;
String forward = "/index.jsp";
if (login == null || password == null || login.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
    errorMessage = res.getString("login_error1");
    request.setAttribute("errorMessageLogin", errorMessage);
    return forward;
}
User user = manager.findUser(login);
if (user == null || !password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
    errorMessage = res.getString("login_error2");
    request.setAttribute("errorMessageLogin", errorMessage);
    return forward;
} else {
    Role userRole = user.getRole();
    forward = "/index.jsp";
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60 * 60);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    session.setAttribute("userRole", userRole);
}
return forward;
}

}
```

This command has method `execute` which returns forward address to servlet - controller.

Comment: Please add some more info. What have you tried? What is the error? This i currently very abstract

Comment: @Avery some code added, can you look please?